# Socket error when getting IP address from a URL

Tags: c#, dns

I am trying to get a website from the user and get the IP address for whatever website the user entered. I have a textbox where the user can enter any website. If the user enters "www.Google.com", then that text goes to `System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(Convert.ToString(urlTextbox));` However, when I run this and test the program out it gives me a socket unhandled error. No such host is found.
What can i do to fix this problem?

This is what i want:
This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
namespace Challenger
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int ipWidth;
        string x;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            urlTextbox.Text ="www.";  
            ipLabelText();                  
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Net.IPAddress[] addresses =
                System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(Convert.ToString(urlTextbox));
            string ipTextLength = Convert.ToString(addresses[0]);

            //Stores the amount of digits
            ipWidth = ipTextLength.Length;

            //Puts ip into a string-> Label for Display
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(addresses[0]);
            label2.Location = new Point(80, 20);
        }

        public void ipLabelText()
        {
            label2.Parent = panel1;
            label2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            label2.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
//Porting LOIC Android Application in C#
```

Answer (score 0):

GetHostByAddress takes an ip address and returns a host name.  So if you put in 8.8.8.8 it would return the name of a google dns server.  The method you are looking for is: [getHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx)

The example from microsoft is:

```
public static void DoGetHostEntry(string hostname)
{
    IPHostEntry host;   
    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);
    Console.WriteLine("GetHostEntry({0}) returns:", hostname);
    foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}", ip);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code in question doesn't use `GetHostByAddress`. And if the OP needs only the IP addresses, the `GetHostAddresses` method (which _is_ being used) works fine, at least when called with a valid host name. :)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to have investigated this would have been for you to step through the code to see in the debugger what you are *actually* passing to the `Dns.GetHostAddresses()` method.

Doing that, you would have seen that the call `Convert.ToString(urlTextbox)` will return a string that looks something like "System.Windows.Controls.TextBox: www.Google.com". As you can see, that's hardly a valid host name. It's not much of a surprise that you get a DNS error. :)

Instead, try `Dns.GetHostAddresses(urlTextbox.Text)`.